# Android WallpaperManager: start intent to crop and resize picture - problems with Uri

Tags: android, file, uri

I am trying to use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent method of WallpaperManager class, but face problems with uri it need. First I tried to get Uri from drawable resourse, but I concluded that this is impossible, and decided to write file to internal storage and get its Uri. Now it gives an error, that uri type must be content. How can I fix this error? Maybe writing file to memory is totally wrong and there are other solutions?
Here is my code:

```
 public void onclick(View v){
        switch (v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.set:

           // try{
                //R.drawable.file1
                File file =new File(this.getFilesDir(),getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.file1));
                file.setWritable(true);
                if (!file.exists())
                {
                    Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.file1);
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
              Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent i=wmanager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(uri);
                    startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.clear:
                try{
                    wmanager.clear();
                }
                catch (IOException ioex){
                    ioex.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

    }
```

Comment: you have to use content scheme uri, not a file

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same problem, fixed by following method and works fine.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) private void setWallpaperKitkat(File file) {
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER);
  String mime = "image/*";
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
  try {
    startActivity(intent);
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: documentation: "Do not use directly to construct an intent; instead, use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri).", this answer needs to down vote